# PHP Mail BCC recpients ignored

Tags: php, email

I am struggling this BCC.
I have 2 email addresses that I've included in the BCC field, but only the first email in the field gets the message, the second email is ignored.

i don't know what am doing wrong.

my code is below

```
$EmailListHere = 'mail1@domain.com,mail2@domain.com';
$headers  = "From: ".$_POST['from-address']."\nX-Mailer: php\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; #Define MIME Version
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n"; #Set content type
$headers .= "Bcc: $EmailListHere\n"; #Your BCC Mail List

echo mail(null, $subject=$_POST['subject'], $message=$_POST['html-body'], $headers);
```

Comment: Are you sure both emails are active and working? If you switch them around, does it still only send to the first?

Comment: @Rylee Yes, both mails are active, when i switch them around, it does the same, delivers to the first one.